# How to have multiple sections with the same name in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I am using EclipseLink Moxy as my JAXB provider and presently facing issues in getting the XML marshalled in an expected fashion.

I presently have an object which is having multiple objects.

```
Object 1 having 
@XmlElement(name="Section")
Object2

@XmlElement(name="Section")
Object3
```

I want to get the XML rendered as:

```
<Object1>
  <Section>
     <Object2>...
  </Section>
  <Section>
     </Object3>...
  </Section>
</Object1>
```

I am using Moxy but I am not able to get the desired result. I tried creating a list of objects

```
@XmlElement(name="Section")
List<Object> sectionsList = new Array<Object>();
```

but this gives me the object path and not the expected XML. Can someone please help ?